# Randomly place and scale objects?

Tags: workflow

I want to create an abstract rendering of lots of cubes floating in the sky. It would be good if they could also be clustered together. I'm thinking of something sort of like this:

[image]

Does Blender have any tools for placing clusters of objects, and randomly scaling them? What's the best process to do this?

Comment: You could easily create a simple Python script for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best tool for this situation is the randomize transform tool. It's not a tool that has a shortcut key and it's buried in the object menu (*Object > Transform > Randomize Transform*), so the easiest way to access it is to simply search it using <kbd>Space</kbd>.

To create the wall from that image, do the following:

1. Create a plane for the wall.
2. Duplicate a few cubes around
3. Use the randomize transform tool and set it to affect the location of the objects (except the axis along the wall) and the scale of the object. Something like this:

   [image: randomized values]
4. You'll get something like this:
   [image: final result]

Answer (score 3):

Create a big cube as a particle system and define an cubic (or any shaped object) as particle. Use volume as emitter and turn off "render emitter" and change the default halo to object, select your cube. Play around with the settings in physic for different particle behaviour...

The particle size can be randomized as well.

Comment: Can the X, Y, and Z scale be randomized independently?

Comment: @Keavon You could use *Group* instead of *Object* and set it to a group of randomly scaled cubes. (perhaps with a python script)