# Is it possible to show the history on a detachable window?

Tags: modeling

My question is: Is it possible to show the history of what I did in blender, possibly as a separate grab-able window that stays on top of the other windows?

I am a blender novice, with no prior experience of any kind and I am open to any solution to the following 2 problems:

1) Blender has so many functions I sometimes accidentally hit a key on my keyboard and I am unsure if I actually did anything. I am then concerned about hitting ctr-z since I am not sure if anything happened or if I'll see or notice the change if I do in fact undo it.

2) Sometimes when I am selecting (vertices especially) I am afraid my hand moves too much and I translate one by accident. Since the movement would be small, it would be hard to see it happen, but if history showed that a translation when I did not want one occurred, I could keep an eye on the history.

Thank you so much for your replies!

Comment: see: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Greylica/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Undo_and_Redo

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/how-increase-decrease-undo-steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every action you've done is listed on the **[Info Window](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/info.html)**, you can view it if you pull it down.

[image]

The commands are listed in Python and list changes to your file as they are made. They're not editable, nor can you go back or undo form here.

For those of us whose language skills are limited to spoken languages and are code illiterate, the option is the **Undo menu**, accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

It will display a list of steps you can undo. Note that the list cannot be kept open permanently.

[image]

Form the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/undo_and_redo.html)

> Rolling back actions using the Undo History feature will take you back to the action you choose. Much like how you can alternate between going backward in time with Ctrl-Z and then forward with Ctrl-Shift-Z, you can hop around on the Undo timeline as much as you want as long as you do not make a new change. Once you do make a new change, the Undo History is truncated at that point.

The number of undo steps is determined by this setting on the user preferences:

[image]

Depending on your system's RAM, you can set up to 256 undo steps.

Comment: It goes up to 256 for me... (12 Gib of RAM)

Comment: @someonewithpc you are correct, I was gong by the info on the wiki page that... seems outdated...

Comment: Wait. What does 'Global Undo' do? Does disabling it make it editor dependent?

Comment: @someonewithpc see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13847/1853

Comment: This is great. Is it also possible to see the history not just of commands that make modifications, but also purely navigational commands that affect properties like point of view and zoom level?

Comment: @algal For new questions please use the big blue **Ask Question** link at the top of the page

Comment: @cegaton Ecco: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95562/is-it-possible-to-show-the-history-on-a-detachable-window-including-navigationa

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 3.0, you can find the Undo History Section under **`Edit > Undo History`**

Comment: I looked but couldn't found: does undo history have a size setting or does it store all the history?