# Show history in detachable window

Tags: interface

Is it possible to permanently have a window which shows the history of actions taken by the user, akin to the below screenshot from photoshop?

[image: 1]

As a new blender user, I constantly find myself accidentally hitting keys which alter my model in some subtle way that comes back to bite me after it is already too late to undo. A history window would be helpful in realizing whether or not I inadvertently pressed some keybind.

This question is not a duplicate because it was asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46556/is-it-possible-to-show-the-history-on-a-detachable-window) 5 years ago, but the solutions weren't great: either open the info window (hard to read and decode) or use the undo menu (cannot be open permanently).

Comment: unfortunately, the answer is no better now, alas.